# Writing Junit TestCase for Hadoop

Tags: java, junit, hadoop, mapreduce, junit4

Could you please provide your valuable inputs on how I can write a JUnit test case for the private function

```
 private int readCustomLine(Text str, int maxLineLength, int maxBytesToConsume)
      throws IOException {
```

in hadoop.

The function is invoked from the following public function -

```
public int readLine(Text str, int maxLineLength,
                      int maxBytesToConsume) throws IOException {
```

which belog to the **LineReader** Class in the **org.apache.hadoop.util** package.

Pretty confused on this as I have not written any testcases before and one more problem in this regard is that we need to address a big data set over here.

Comment: What version / distro of hadoop are you targetting, and what's the fully qualified name of this readCustomLine method - is it a private method of the LineReader class?

Comment: 0.20.2 version of hadoop. org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader class and Private method readCustomLine

Comment: And what exactly do you want to test for? The Unit test for TestTextInputFormat (http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/tags/release-0.20.2/src/test/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TestTextInputFormat.java?view=markup) does a good job of testing LineReader